# What is a descendant?

Tags: terminology, historical-linguistics

When is a word descended from another word? Is it limited to ancestor-to-child language relationship? If, for example, Spanish borrows from French, is the loanword a descendant of the French word?

Comment: I'm not aware of _descendant word_ as an established phrase, so if I encountered it in a text I would not necessarily know whether the writer meant to include or exclude borrowings.

Comment: Take for example the Wiktionary entry [gutta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gutta).

Comment: Ah. So, I look in Wiktionary's [Entry layout](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Entry_layout#Descendants) and I find that **there** it means "terms in other languages that have borrowed or inherited the word." That doesn't mean that other sources will use it the same way.

Comment: @ColinFine. That is one of the many problems with Wiktionary.

Comment: @fdb. I agree. But at least it does specify exactly what it means, if you know where to look.

Answer (score 5):

In linguistics we distinguish (usually) between descendants and borrowings. French chauve "bald" is a descendant of Latin calvus. French calvitie "baldness" is borrowed from Latin calvities.

Comment: For instance, note the various different descendant and borrowed cognates to various PIE roots in English: _[*penkʷe_](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/penkwe.pdf), _[*sed-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sed.pdf)_, _[*dei-](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/dei.pdf)_.